# Unable to conect to postgres server using Local IP Address as my host (for eg: 192.168.x.x)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

[image]
I am using postgres 9.6, Working with localhost so far,
Now I am trying to connect my server with local IP, but getting the fatal error
I have modified in pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf file from localhost to my IP address.
could any one please help me out

Here is my pg_hba.conf.sample
[image]

Comment: populate the content of your hba.conf please

Comment: please see the image above, for the pg_hba config file

Comment: `Desktop\pg_hba.conf.sample`?.. start command prompt and run `psql -c "show hba_file"`

Comment: and copy paste formatted text instead of screenshot of np++

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional line to your connections

```
host   all   all   all   md5
```

This will require a password on the PostgreSQL user you intend to connect with. You can adda password to your postgres user for example by doing the following from the psql terminal

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

Then you can connect with username:postgres password:postgres

If this works you may want to make some adjustments to make it more secure